# Verbose list comprehension in Python

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have a list of integers and I want to create a new list with all elements smaller than a given limit.

```
a=range(15) #example list
limit=9 #example limit
```

My approach to solve this problem was

```
[i for i in a if i < limit]
```

To me the beginning 'i for i in' looks pretty verbose. Is there a *better* implementation in Python?

Comment: "pretty verbose"?  How could you reduce that in a general way?  Please provide your preferred syntax.  What are you hoping for?

Comment: @SilentGhost: As always, the term 'better' in Python means following the Zen of Python.

Comment: @S.Lott: Preferred syntax would omit one of the 'i' occurencies, such as [i in a if i<limit]. (Please do not start a flame about my suggestion. I don't claim that this syntax should be added to the python language.)

Comment: Sorry but... -1.  List comprehensions aren't verbose, and if you're interested in being pythonic (e.g. following the Zen), then you should use the heavily-preferred list comprehension whether it's verbose or not.

Comment: @Roland: Please update your question with additional information.  Please don't comment on your own question when you can update it to clarify what you're looking for.

Comment: `[i in a if i<limit else 23]` is perfectly valid syntax for a 1-item list (the one and only item will be True, False, or 23, depending). Having identical syntax without the `else` have a COMPLETELY different meaning -- what a *perfectly horrible* idea!

Comment: Consider: 
   [ name for (name, value) in list_of_tuples if value != None ]
Here the "for" is absolutely necessary to separate the value-to-be-stored from the values-being-produced.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [filter](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#filter)

```
>>> filter(lambda i: i < limit, a)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

But list comprehensions are the preferred way to do it

Here is what [python docs](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) has to say about this:

> List comprehensions provide a concise
>   way to create lists without resorting
>   to use of map(), filter() and/or
>   lambda. The resulting list definition
>   tends often to be clearer than lists
>   built using those constructs.

Comment: This is longer than the example list comprehension!

Answer (score 2):

This is about the best you can do.  You may be able to do better with filter, but I wouldn't recommend it.  Bear in mind that the list comprehension reads almost like english:  "i for i in a if i < limit".  This makes it much easier to read and understand, if a little on the verbose side.

Answer (score 1):

You can use filter() (at least in the Python 2.x series... I think it might have been removed in 3.0)

```
newlist = filter(lambda item: item < limit, oldlist)
```

The first argument can be any callable (its result will be coerced to boolean, so it's best to use a callable that returns boolean anyway), and the second argument can be any sequence.

Answer (score 0):

The nicer versions require boilerplate code, so the list comprehension is as nice as you can get.

This would be one different way to do it:

```
from operator import ge
from functools import partial

filter(partial(ge, limit), a)
```

(But if you were to use `filter`, [Nadia's way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1460484/verbose-list-comprehension-in-python/1460497#1460497) would be the obvious way to do it)